# How do you calculate the likelihood of drawing certain cards in your opening hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, probability

In Magic, at the start of the game, you draw 7 cards. How would you calculate the likelihood of drawing a specific card in your opening hand?

For example, let's say I have a 60 card deck, and I'm running 4 [Birds of Paradise](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Birds%20of%20Paradise). What is the percent chance that I will have at least one Bird in my opening hand?

Answer (score 57):

The calculation you are looking for is called a [Hypergeometric Distribution](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/hypergeometric.aspx). This calculated your chances of drawing a particular number of "successes" from a population, without replacement.

- Population Size: 60 cards
- Successes in Population: 4 Birds of Paradise
- Sample Size: 7 cards
- Successes in Sample: 1 (the minimum number we want to draw)
- Results: 39% chance of drawing at least 1 Birds of Paradise.

In the Hypergeometric Distribution calculator linked above, that result is represented in the *Cumulative Probability: P(X ≥ 1)* field: the chance of drawing greater than or equal to 1.

The online calculator will also give you the odds of drawing greater than that many successes in the sample (6%, the *P(X > 1)* result), and exactly that number (33%, the *Hypergeometric Probability: P(X = 1)* result).

You can see the calculation on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#section_1), or searching math.stackexchange.com for Hypergeometric Distribution. Unfortunately, this site doesn't support math formatting. (Note: You will also need to know how to calculate [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Computing_the_value_of_binomial_coefficients) (and factorials).

Comment: Interesting program, but i was looking for the formula so that i could figure it out on my own.

Comment: That program calculates the odds of getting at least one BoP at 40% if you are going first. Remember, since you draw when you go second the odds rise to 44%.

Comment: @DForck42 why would you want to do it by hand? :) Anyway, I think the full answer would fall out of scope for this stack exchange. The answer to your question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24211/what-is-the-probability-of-n-people-from-a-list-of-m-people-being-in-a-random-se

Comment: Why WOULDN'T you want to do it by hand!? :P

Comment: Question is looking for "At least one," yet answer provides "exactly one."

Comment: @DrunkCynic, yes my answer is for exactly a certain number of successes, but using that, you can calculate it for exactly 1, exactly 2, exactly 3, etc. successes and then add them all together.

Comment: @user1873 I understand the inter-workings of the hypergeometric distribution, and took no other issue with the answer. Using the calculator you linked, the at least one is just the "X >= 1" result, ~40%.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Isn't that what user1873 said in the sentence directly following his bullet points?

Comment: @ghoppe, well bollocks for tunnel vision.

Answer (score 34):

The odds of drawing a particular card in a 60-card deck are obviously 1/60. If there are four such cards, the odds are 4/60. The odds of NOT drawing one of those cards in the first draw is 1 - 4/60 = 56/60.

To calculate the odds of the entire first hand, we can do it backwards:

The odds of not having any of the four cards in the first card is 56/60 (as I said above). The second card has odds of 55/59 (i.e. one of the remaining non-Bird cards after a non-Bird card was drawn to start), and then 54/58 and so on:

- Card 1: 56/60 chance of not being the card you targeted
- Card 2: 55/59
- Card 3: 54/58
- Card 4: 53/57
- Card 5: 52/56
- Card 6: 51/55
- Card 7: 50/54

The odds of ALL of these happening (i.e. none of the four cards being in your hand) is the result of multiplying all these odds together:

(56*55*54*53*52*51*50) / (60*59*58*57*56*55*54) = ~0.6005 or ~60%

To calculate the odds of at least one of these cards being the one you're looking for, you can subtract this result from 1 (or 100%) to get a **~40% chance that (at least) one of your four cards will occur in a 7-card draw from a 60-card deck**.

Comment: user1873 had the correct answer, but I've written out the working to answer the comments to that first answer.

Answer (score 8):

[Magic Workstation](http://www.magicworkstation.com/) besides many other tools for collection management, deck building, and online play has a very powerful probability calculator.  It will go beyond opening hand and will let you see by what turn are you likely to have drawn the combo that you need.

Comment: Magic Workstation appears to be offline/gone, but I found this alternative (which seems pretty easy to use): https://www.mtgnexus.com/tools/drawodds