# How likely am I to have a key card in my starting hand in Brawl?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, probability, mtg-brawl

I'm playing the Brawl format (a 60-card singleton format), and I really want one specific card in my starting hand.

I'm willing to take two mulligans (leaving me with a starting hand of 5 cards after putting 2 on the bottom of my library).

What are the odds of drawing **the** card in my opening hand within 2 mulligans?

Comment: [Hers already a hint how to calculate this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7850/how-do-you-calculate-the-likelihood-of-drawing-certain-cards-in-your-opening-hand)

Comment: You currently have a few questions peppered in there. For the avoidance of doubt, it would be good to remove all but the questions in the last paragraph.

Comment: The question Aetherfox refers to is very different from this. In my opinion, this is not a duplicate.It is true that they are similar; however, this is a different probability problem, as this question asks about the probability of obtaining a specific card even AFTER making two mulligans - and therefore it is about "probability with re-entry in the initial sample".Furthermore, in the other question a very different example is made, in which the probability of having a particular card in the initial hand is requested, but of which there are 4 copies in the deck.I don't think that's the case...

Comment: @Aetherfox Re "*Does this answer your question?*", It does not. The linked question doesn't cover mulligans whatsoever. (It also about a different deck size and a different number of target cards.)

Comment: Doh! I didn't want to unilaterally reopen the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first mulligan is free in Brawl<sup>[CR 903.11g]</sup>, so it's 3 mulligans leaves you with 5 cards. I shall reply accordingly.

After removing the Commander, 59 cards remain in the deck. 58 of those aren't *the card*.

The probability that the 1st card drawn isn't *the card* is 58/59.
The probability that the 2nd card drawn also isn't *the card* is 57/58.
The probability that the 3rd card drawn also isn't *the card* is 56/57.
etc.

So the probability that you don't have *the card* in your opening hand
= (58/59)*(57/58)*(56/57)*(55/56)*(54/55)*(53/54)*(52/53)
= (58*57*56*55*54*53*52)/(59*58*57*56*55*54*53)
= 52/59

Since you draw seven card from a freshly shuffled deck when taking a mulligan, the probably of not getting *the card* in a mulligan is the same as for the initial hand.

So the probability that you don't have *the card* after up to three mulligans
= (52/59)^4
= 60%

The probability that you do have the *the card* after up to three mulligans
= 1 - 60%
= 40%

---

Probabilities are easy to get wrong, so I like to verify through experimentation.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( shuffle );

use constant NUM_TRIALS => 10_000;

my @deck = ( 1, (0)x58 );
my $successes = 0;
for (1..NUM_TRIALS) {
   for (7,7,6,5) {
      if ( grep { $_ } ( shuffle(@deck) )[0..6] ) {
         ++$successes;
         last;
      }
   }
}

printf("%.0f%%\n", $successes/NUM_TRIALS * 100);
```

Output:

```
$ ./a
40%

$ ./a
40%

$ ./a
39%
```

---

The current rules for mulligans:

> 103.4. Each player draws a number of cards equal to their starting hand size, which is normally seven. (Some effects can modify a player’s starting hand size.) A player who is dissatisfied with their initial hand may take a mulligan. First, the starting player declares whether they will take a mulligan. Then each other player in turn order does the same. Once each player has made a declaration, all players who decided to take mulligans do so at the same time. **To take a mulligan, a player shuffles the cards in their hand back into their library, draws a new hand of cards equal to their starting hand size, then puts a number of those cards equal to the number of times that player has taken a mulligan on the bottom of their library in any order.** Once a player chooses not to take a mulligan, the remaining cards become that player’s opening hand, and that player may not take any further mulligans. This process is then repeated until no player takes a mulligan. A player can take mulligans until their opening hand would be zero cards, after which they may not take further mulligans.
>
> 903.11g In any Brawl game, the first mulligan a player takes doesn’t count toward the number of cards that player will put on the bottom of their library or the number of mulligans that player may take. Subsequent mulligans are counted toward these numbers as normal.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: This answer appears to use a mulligan rule different than given on the Wizards website:  https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/formats/brawl  Card draws are 7, 7, 6, 5 as I read the rules.  Not 7, 7, 7, 7 as this answer states.

Comment: But with the London mulligan rule you  draw 7 and discard down to 6 or 5. So the odd can be calculated on 7 if you are only looking for one card.

Comment: The question is specified in the sense that the player starts with 7 cards in hand; and then the first mulligan is made, drawing only 6;then, the second mulligan consists, based on what is requested by the application, of a third drawing of only 5 cards. The answers must be based on this data.

Comment: Thank you @Styxsksu, I wasn't aware of the London Mulligan rule.

Comment: @John, You should follow your own link :) That is not how mulligans work in MTG (anymore). Please read 103.4 (and 903.11g), now conveniently quoted in my answer.

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin, Re "*The question is specified in the sense that the player starts with 7 cards in hand; and then the first mulligan is made, drawing only 6*", No, it's not. That is not how mulligans work in MTG (anymore), the OP specifically indicated they know how it works (since they referenced putting cards on the bottom of the deck as part of doing a mulligan).

Comment: If so, you are right Ikegami. Even if this really leaves me perplexed ... I can't believe it: can a player see all seven cards even in the three mulligans after the first draw, and choose the 5 or 6 ones to hold in his hand? That's why this game has lost charm ... in this way it is practically always worth taking Mulligan ... –

Comment: @ManoFromBerlin, It is more favorable than the old method. (Answer to the question using the old way: 32% Answer to the question using the new way: 40%). But not by much. That means that every 25 games, you'll get the card in your starting hand twice more.

Answer (score -3):

**Odds for non-Brawl using the pre-Core 2020 mulligan rules** (according to Ikegami's editing)

The probability of having a desired card in the hand,at the first draw of seven cards, is, by removing the commander, (7/59) * 100 = **11.8644%**

If, at the first draw, the desired card has not arrived, then, according to what is stated in the question, you will draw again using the mulligan; and then the probability of reaching this point, which is obviously greater than 7/59, is as follows -

- first of all, this probability is due to the probability of **not** drawing the desired card to the first set of seven cards, which is: (52/59) * 100 = **88.1356%**
- this value is then multiplied by the probability of drawing the desired card **now**, which, **having returned the 7 first cards in the deck**, but now having to draw 6, is (6/59) * 100 = **10.1695%**
- Consequently, the probability of one mulligan, and then of finding the card sought in the six cards of the second draw is (52/59) * (6/59) * 100 = **8.9629%**

If the card you are looking for hasn't arrived at this point, then, as specified in the question, you will mulligan for the second time.

So, this probability is obtained by multiplying the value of the probability of **not** drawing the card among the first seven (52/59), multiplied by the probability of **not** drawing the card even the second time (53/59), multiplied by the probability of draw the desired card **now**, but drawing only 5, or 5/59.

Consequently, the probability of mulligan twice, and then of finding the card sought among the five cards of the third draw is: (52/59) * (53/59) * (5/59) = **6.7%**

At this point, the total probability of finding a desired "key-card", being able to make two mulligans, is given by the sum of the three possibilities of finding the card:

(possibility of finding the card after the first draw) + (possibility of finding the card after the first mulligan) + (possibility of finding the card after the second mulligan) =
11.8644+ 8.9629+ 6.7 = **27.5273%**

Well ... that's all ... at least I think.
I hope there are no typing and/or math errors !!!

---

**Odds for Brawl using the Core 2020 mulligan rules**

The result shown above works only if, in making Mulligan the first time, the player draws 6 cards (not 7), and, in making Mulligan the second time, if the player draws only 5.
In addition, **the result is valid only without looking at the cards that are placed at the bottom of the deck**.
But, as I suspected, this does not accord with the current Mulligan rule...

I think I will leave this answer here just the same, also because, even if it refers to a mulligan rule that is not now applied, its procedure is correct.
To prove it, I will verify that his calculations are correct, rewriting them taking into account my own procedure, but considering the correct Mulligan rule.
The probability of having a desired card in the hand, at the first draw of seven cards, is, by removing the Commander, (7/59) * 100 = **11.8644%**.

The probability of having the card at the first mulligan is:
(52/59)*(7/59)*100 = **10.4567652973%**.

The probability of having the card at the second mulligan is:
(52/59)*(52/59)*(7/59)*100 =**9.21613212646%**.

(This means that the player is able to, according to the current Mulligan rules, look at 7 cards, and choose for himself the **one** that will be placed at the bottom of the deck, according to his needs. And it is always for this reason that the calculations agree based on the fact that, making Mulligan, for the purpose of searching for a "key card", it is as if the player was still drawing seven cards).

The probability of having the card at the third Mulligan - 
(or when, granting the answer to the fact that the asker claims to want to stay,at most,with 5 cards in hand, after the Mulligans, which, however, are 3, and therefore not 2) - 
is:
(52/59)*(52/59)*(52/59)*(7/59)*100=**8.12269272162%**

(And this also means that the player is able to, according to the current Mulligan rules, look at 7 cards, and choose for himself the **two** that will be placed at the bottom of the deck, according to his needs).

At this point, **the total probability of finding a desired "key-card"**, being able to make three mulligans, is given by the sum of the four possibilities of finding the card. And **is**:

11.8644% + 10.4567652973% + 9.21613212646% + 8.12269272162%= **39.6590927216%**.

This result is absolutely close to the correct one, already calculated in the right answer, higher.

Comment: If so, you are right Ikegami. Even if this really leaves me perplexed ... I can't believe it: can a player see all seven cards even in the two mulligans after the first draw, and choose the 5 or 6 ones to hold in his hand? That's why this game has lost charm ... in this way it is practically always worth taking Mulligan ...

Comment: Anyway, I think Ikegami's 40% is really too high ... It is equal to take almost 24 cards,but in only one draw...while here we are talking about taking 21 cards,in three draws,and in the best case! But...Ok...Ikegami has right: it is equal to take 28 cards,in 4 draws, and because the first mulligan means to draw 7 cards, just as it was the first time. It is this way...but it is also unbelievable...These new and honeyed in syrup rules are killing me ...Mulligan should be an exception, but this way it becomes the rule instead, because it is too convenient to do it!

Comment: But no!Your calculation is absolutely right, Ikegami.But mine is too,and you can still leave it here with the new editing, because now the steps are well specified and can be followed well by anyone in this way.And then, if the current Mulligan rule were to change, there would be all the procedure specified step by step. Anyway, you are right, Ikegami:you calculated everything before and correctly, because you know the rules of the game much better than me! You have to admit, however, that kind of Mulligan is the rule,not the exception.You first say:-"Ok, players:make your hand as you please!"

Comment: Re "*But mine is too*", Well, now they are.

Comment: Re "*This result is absolutely close to the correct one, already calculated in the right answer, higher.*", It's the same answer; I simply rounded to the nearest %. No point in being more precise.

Comment: Your answer came first,and has been rightly accepted.My incorrect answer makes yours stand out.I carried out the calculations independently of your answer, and in the end,having ascertained thanks to you that the Mulligan rule to which I referred was incorrect,I showed how the procedures were still correct both.And then,in this way I point out that this Mulligan rule is in my opinion excessive. Ok, that's the rule: but I think that having the chance to always see all the 7 cards,at each Mulligan,and choose the ones that serve the most,is excessive. But I'm only an useless dreamer...

Comment: However, there is another good reason why I think this answer may still have reason to be left where it is.

Comment: The OP may know the current Mulligan rule; after Ikegami's answer,certainly yes; but,before asking the question,he might not even know it at all, OR would not want to refer to it. Based on the question,the asker demonstrates - it is true - that he knows that the discarded Mulligans'cards go to the bottom of the deck. But, assumed that he talks about 2 Mulligans instead of 3, as he does in the question,he could actually talk about a personalized Mulligan procedure to be carried out in the manner that the asker himself describes in the question.

Comment: Then,the data that I used during the first part of the answer,agree exactly with the Mulligan as described by the OP,which may not be the one in force at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103457/discussion-between-manofromberlin-and-ikegami).

Comment: On the other hand, if the question is structured in this way,in the sense that the OP specifies clear that he wants to do 2 mulligans - and besides,even the editing of Ikegami himself does not correct what he himself calls as an "OP's error",and still reports the fact of running a maximum of two(not three) mulligans remaining with 5 cards in hand,even in the edited question - I do not see what is so inappropriate in responding even taking into account the possibility of a "customized mulligan",or regarding the past rules.Then,Ikegami is right:OP certainly means the actual Brawl's Mulligan Rule

Comment: Are you seriously claiming the fact that I think the OP wants to do 3 mulligans is a problem? If someone wants to calculate the odds for a different number of mulligan, they just need to replace the `4` in `(52/59)^4`. Remember, a good answer shows *how* to do something rather than just giving the answer for this very reason. (That's also why I calculated the odds in terms of not finding the card. Your approach only works because every card is different.)

Comment: No, seriously Ikegami, your answer is the best. But I did many things: 1) 
 I reviewed the Post; 2) I compared the Post with those to which it had been wrongly associated; 3) I found that it is not a duplicate, as other users had stated - and on this point, Ikegami, it seems to me that we have always agreed, and we only; 4) Then, I answered the question, doing all the calculations,but with a procedure very different  from yours, to show an alternative way of answering.

Comment: I believe that for all these reasons, and others too, it is right that my answer should be considered as a good attempt. Considering also that my questions have always been subject to dubious duplications, and that they are always well-edited to eliminate any type of error, it seems to me that I have done well what I have been asked to do. Then, it's true ikegami: your answers are always excellent, and it is very difficult to overcome them, for anyone ...

Comment: I'm confused. Who said it wasn't a good attempt? And why would anyone care?